# R - Select specific rows within group of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, row

I have a dataframe like the following one:

```
     ID          STATUS
1638483        Very bad
1407499       Very good
1383920            Good
1407499             Bad
```

First  column contains `ID`, some are unique but some others are not.
Second column contains `STATUS` which can be: `"Very good"`, `"Good"`, `"Bad"`, or `"Very Bad"`.

I'd like to:

- **keep rows with unique `ID` (`STATUS` does not matter here)**: rows with `ID` `1638483` or `1383920`  for example,
- **select only rows with the best status for rows with non-unique `ID`**: rows with `ID` `1407499` for example

The desired output would be:

```
     ID          STATUS
1638483        Very bad
1407499       Very good
1383920            Good
```

I tried to use the `dplyr` package. 
I succeed to group data by `ID` but then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution using dplyr:

```
# create tibble
df <- tibble(
  id = c("1638483", "1407499", "1383920", "1407499"),
  status = c("Very bad", "Very good", "Good", "Bad")
)

# solution
df %>%
  mutate_at("status", factor, 
            levels = c("Very bad", "Bad", "Good", "Very good")) %>%
  arrange(desc(status)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(status == status[1]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       id    status
    <chr>    <fctr>
1 1383920      Good
2 1407499 Very good
3 1638483  Very bad
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have several rows with "Very good" how can I keep all of them instead of just keeping one of them with slice(1) ?

Comment: You can replace `slice(1)` by `filter(status == status[1])`.

Comment: Thanks! It will just work with "Very good' status right? What if the best status in each group varies? Let's say we have a group with several "Very good" and another with several "Good". Is it possible to do something similar ?

Comment: It will work for any status. If the "best status" of an id is not "Very good" and multiple rows of that id have this same status, they will all be retained in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `STATUS` to `factor` according to desired `levels` and use `ave`

```
df$STATUS = factor(df$STATUS, levels = c("Very bad", "Bad", "Good", "Very good"))
df[ave(as.numeric(df$STATUS), df$ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)) == 1,]
#       ID    STATUS
#1 1638483  Very bad
#2 1407499 Very good
#3 1383920      Good
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(ID = c(1638483L, 1407499L, 1383920L, 1407499L), 
    STATUS = c("Very bad", "Very good", "Good", "Bad")), .Names = c("ID", 
"STATUS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @Henrik, I couldn't get that to work, but `aggregate(STATUS ~ ID, df, function(x) x[which.max(as.numeric(x))])` worked

Comment: I used `ordered = TRUE`.I missed that you didn't. Sorry for the confusion. I.e. `d$STATUS <- factor(d$STATUS, levels = c("Very_bad", "Bad", "Good", "Very_good"), ordered = TRUE)`; `aggregate(STATUS ~ ID, max, data = d)`